# Adding new row to multicolumn listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am new to android and in my application i have a multi column listview and i need to add new row or item to listview on button click..i try a lot of solutions from here and also from a lot of websites but my problem is not solved i attach my code here please anyone help.

layout 1(including a list view listOrders)

layout 2(listview_row.xml)

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.27"
    android:text="Item" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtQuantity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.12"
    android:text="Quantity" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
```

main Activity

```
public class AddOrderActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener 
{
private ListView list;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
private HashMap<String, String> map;
SimpleAdapter mSchedule;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activityaddorder);   
Button btnAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(this);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
// used to show the heading of listview
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("txtItem", "Item");
map.put("txtQuantity", "Quantity");
map.put("txtTotal", "Total");
mylist.add(map);
mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(AddOrderActivity.this, mylist, R.layout.listview_row,
new String[] { "txtItem", "txtQuantity", "txtTotal" }, new int[] {
R.id.txtItem, R.id.txtQuantity, R.id.txtTotal });
list.setAdapter(mSchedule); 
}

@Override
//i want to add new row on this button click
public void onClick(View v) {
map = null;
map.put("txtItem", "1");
map.put("txtQuantity", "2");
map.put("txtTotal", "2");
mylist.add(map);    
mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged();   
finish();       
}
}
```

the heading is correct but when i click to button the app will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some mistakes in your code. Try this.

```
@Override 
onClick(View v) { 
    map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("txtItem", "1");
    map.put("txtQuantity", "2"); 
    map.put("txtTotal", "2");
    mylist.add(map);    

    mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(AddOrderActivity.this, mylist, R.layout.listview_row,new String[] { "txtItem", "txtQuantity", "txtTotal" }, new int[] {
R.id.txtItem, R.id.txtQuantity, R.id.txtTotal });  

    list.setAdapter(mSchedule); 
    } 
}
```

you shouldn't initialize the map = null (you obtain anNullPointerException in that code)

and you must set the adapter again with the new Map.

I hope that it works.

Comment: thanks for the code now the new row is added correctly but at first button click 2 rows are add and also the heading will replace by one row (both rows have same value 1 2 2) and  remaining all click it only add single row

Comment: first one is correct and there is no need to set the adapter again in onclick().only need to call the mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged() method after adding data to mylist